# How to create Google cloud VM instance(windows) with custom username and password through REST API?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

Through google cloud console, we can reset password and can give custom username for VM Instances(windows), But we want to achieve same thing using REST API , but we couldn't find. 
As we can create password through GCloud CommandLine, but is there any API's to create.

Kindly help to find the REST API

Comment: What type of instance is this? (Linux, Windows, something else?) Additionally, I'd remove the C# tag if I were you - it doesn't sound like this is really C# specific as a question, even if you want to use it from C#. If someone knows about the REST API to use, that would get you started - if you then had trouble *using* it from C#, that could be a separate question.

Comment: Actually i got creating password for windows instances through GCLOUD Command Line  but, i couldn't find through API's. I just want to know whether API's are there to create.

Comment: So is it Windows instances that you're trying to change? It would help if you'd update the question to be clearer - if you show the `gcloud` command line you've been able to use, that would help too.